# Is it safe to delete Recovery, ESP and Push Button Reset partitions before a new OS install?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fresh-install

Basically the title, but I already did some search and ESP is my main worry since it is related to boot files.

I'm doing a new fresh install of Windows on a notebook, and I'd like to delete everything that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows 10 fresh install creates 3 partitions:  UEFI partition, Recovery partition, and Data Partition.

**(A) What is needed at the conclusion of the install:**

You need the last one, very obviously.

Do NOT delete the UEFI partition as it is needed to start the computer.

I recommend not deleting the Recovery partition as you might need it (when you least expect to need it). It is small.

So keep the 3 partitions that Windows 10 creates.  Windows 11 is very similar.

**(B) What can be deleted prior to fresh install:**

Now when doing a fresh install, yes, of course you can delete all partitions as Windows 10 will create them anew.

I recommend having a full backup before you delete partitions and start fresh.

If you have a top brand computer, get the Recovery USB as it will create the 3 partitions, one of which will the branded Recovery partition.